# PhpExcel setCellValue don't write anything

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to show an Excel file with some database variables. So I use PhpExcel, and I write this :

```
$row = 5;
$excel->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row, 'TEST');
```

And it not works ! But.. I use :

```
$excel->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 5, 'TEST');
```

It works ! I really can't understand the problem, my loop don't work, but if I use numbers, it does. Someone already had this problem ?

Comment: Are the $row numbers what you think they are? Because there's no reason that it would fail otherwise

Comment: Yes they are. But I found solution, I write in the same column after... But it's weird, with direct number in function, it works, but not with variable containing number.

Comment: There's no fault with that method that could fail if $row is a valid number.... unless you've found some incredibly obscure PHP bug. The only circumstance in which it could make it a difference is if the argument was pass by reference, which it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. I just write in the same row after. I write an empty string, so I didn't notice it. But it's weird, with direct number in function, it works, but not with variable containing number.